# Any way of knowing who got the most Unicoins?

Tags: support, unicoins, april-fools

I had just about reached 1,000 Unicoins *after* having bought all the powerups, but was able to continue mining for an entire day after the feature was removed from being visible on the site (which was trippy!) but now I have no idea how many Unicoins I actually ended up with.

Is there any way to find out this information? (It's Unicoins on SO, btw, not Meta.SO)

Comment: Jon Skeet earned the most unicoins. You can take my word for it.

Comment: Is this a "Who built the best mining script" competition?

Comment: @Pollyanna Well not really, because I did, but what I want to know is was my horrifically bad luck enough to make others get more coins than me XD

Comment: I'd also be curious how many clicks on rocks were made. Millions? Billions?

Comment: You are really asking the wrong question. What you should be asking is "Why does it matter?" ;)

Answer (score 10):

Nobody has any unicoins. They were all stolen from Stack Exchange by a rogue unicorn who exploited a little-known bug in the implementation of the unicoin exchange. This is why nobody could buy or sell unicoins for so long.

Comment: BoltClock!  I knew it!

Comment: @Jamal BoltClock, first name Usain

Answer (score 9):

No, not really. We just stored the Unicoin balance in Redis per-user, and there's no easy way to query that. The theoretical maximum was probably in the ballpark of 3000-4000 (I didn't simulate or calculate this exactly though, just a rough guess), but that's only if you mined throughout the 50 hours that it was April 1st [AoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth), not just the 24 hours it was visible in your browser without changing your computer's timezone.

Comment: "no easy way to query that" - since when did it stop SE dev? ;-)